# Function in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I create a function named TotalGross that will compute the sum of the paycheck gross amounts for a specific employee?

It should look like

Fname     Lname    Earnings

Comment: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm) is a documentation how a function is build

Comment: well that depends on the table structure of your database

Comment: What is your actual question? How to create a PL/SQL function in Oracle? How to use SUM in an SQL query? How to limit an SQL query such as to only consider specific records (for a specific employee in your case)?

Comment: A function seems like overkill for something that can be done with a simple query. Why do you want a function?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  You will get better results that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to add the amount of several paychecks.
Try this

```
Select Fname, Lname, Sum(Earnings * 52)
From Table_Name
Group By Fname, Lname, Earnings;
```